# django social media apps ManyToManyField population issue

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I am writing a social media app with django. I designed a model, but when I try to populate it, it throws this error:

```
ValueError at /admin/social/group/add/

"<Group: Group object (None)>" needs to have a value for field "id" before this many-to-many relationship can be used.
```

These are my models:

```
from django.db import models


class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)


class Group(models.Model):
    admin = models.ForeignKey(
        Person, 
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='group_admin'
    )
    members = models.ManyToManyField(
        Person, 
        related_name='group_members',
        blank=True
    )

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.members.add(self.admin)
        super(Group, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

I want that the `admin` will also be a `group` member.

When I keep the `save` method like this...

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(Group, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
    self.members.add(self.admin)
```

...it doesn't throw any error but also the members field does not populate as intended.

I want to achieve that while submitting an admin during the creation of a `Group`, the members field will be filled automatically with same foreign key of admin.

I mean, an `admin` will be in `members` of the same group.

Can anyone help me to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Overwriting the `save` method of a model can be tricky and is oftentimes not the best solution to a given challenge.

Another approach you could try is a [`post_save` signal](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/signals/#post-save) (though signals are also contested!).

It could look something like this in your **models.py**:

```py
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver


class Group(models.Model):
    admin = ...
    members = ...


@receiver(post_save, sender=Group)
def add_admin_to_members(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    """
    adds self.admin to self.members when Group is created
    """

    if created and instance.admin:
        instance.members.add(instance.admin)
```

When you create a `Group` with an `admin` elsewhere like so...

```
Group.objects.create(admin=SomeUser)
```

..., the `add_admin_to_members` function will be executed as it is connected to the `post_save` signal of the `Group` model.

**EDIT**

Check [this repository](https://github.com/creimers/so-reproduce) for a demonstration of what is described in the answer. Especially check the [test case](https://github.com/creimers/so-reproduce/blob/master/so_reproduce/so_app/test_models.py).

Comment: I know i can achieve it by signal but i want to achieve it by save method

Comment: Anyway, Also, It cant be achived by signal, Did you try yourself like you described?

Comment: Had a tiny mistake in the anser. It should be `instance.admin` instead of `self.admin`. Corrected. See [this repo](https://github.com/creimers/so-reproduce) for proof of concept.